# How to copy elasticsearch indices from file system to my pc?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to copy elasticsearch data from file system. in my server, my indices are here:

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices
```

I zipped all data here and moved to my elasticsearch on my PC exactly in the same path.
but I can not see my indices when I try:

```
localhost:9200/_cat/indices
```

What should I do?
Server elasticsearch version: 1.7.3
PC elasticsearch version: 5.5.0

Comment: The indices created in ES 1.7.3 cannot be read in ES 5.5.0 simply by copying the binary segment files, you need to reindex them.

Comment: @Val How to reindex? is there a command?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines listed here for upgrades between 1.x and 5.x: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of moving indexes from 1 box to another in ES is through the [snapshot and restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) APIs that ES provides.
But -

- A snapshot of an index created in 2.x can be restored to 5.x.
- A snapshot of an index created in 1.x can be restored to 2.x.
- A snapshot of an index created in 1.x ***can not*** be restored to 5.x.

So for you to get it working, you would have to -

1. Take a snapshot from 1.7 and restore it in 2.4
2. Take a snapshot from 2.4 and restore it in 5.x